# Problems with HttpMethod.releaseConnection() and EntityUtils.consume(entity)

Tags: java, android, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm having a problem: I've just copied the following code from NetBeans to Eclipse (an ADT project). I've imported all the same librarys I used in NetBeans, but I have 2 errors, in the following lines:

`EntityUtils.consume(entity);` - The method consume(HttpEntity) is undefined for the type EntityUtils

`httpPut.releaseConnection();` - The method releaseConnection() is undefined for the type HttpPut

Complete code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import com.android.lul.classes.User;

public class UserService {

    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/LULServices/webresources";

    public static String Login (String login, String password, String ipAdd)
    {
        String toReturn = null;

        final DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
                httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("localhost", 8080),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx"));

        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(BASE_URI + "/services.users/login");
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 10000);

        httpPut.addHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "login"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));

        httpPut.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);

        try {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String putResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                toReturn = putResponse;
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            } finally {
                httpPut.releaseConnection();
            }

            } finally {
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            return toReturn;
        }
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: do you understant what the error means?

Comment: Yes, like Robby said, "Apache HttpClient that doesn't have those methods". I thought it was a problem of imports, but I have all the imports I used in NetBeans, and there all went fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android comes with a prepackaged version of Apache HttpClient that doesn't have those methods. They are no longer supporting development and that code is outdated.

The Android team recommends that you use [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for new code instead of HttpClient. More information can be found at this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) on the Android Developers site.

Comment: That blog is from 2011

Comment: Uploading a file using HttpUrlConnection is almost like building a GUI with assembler.

Comment: thats the problem with android java development, they are trying their best to make it harder and harder for developer, never like android development, hate it...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should follow a simpler example, as this one seems to be meant to upload files (multipart/form-data), but regarding the specific problems in your code:

1. Instead of `EntityUtils.consume(entity);` you can do `entity.consumeContent();`
   http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html
2. The HTTPRequest classes (HttpPost, HttpPut) don't have any `releaseConnection()` method. Probably because they don't need to be released (somebody correct me if I'm wrong). That method is usually applicable for persistent connections which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports; What version of Apache HttpComponents are you using in your new project?