# not able to release connection while using Apache HTTPClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HTTPCLient API's in my android app. After having made a getRequest , I wanted to release the connection . As per the javadoc the available method is request.releaseConnection(). When i used that method in normal java project, it worked. But when I use it in my android project, Eclipse annoys me with red squiggly line and doesn't list that method in suggestion list  too.

I referred to this question

[Problems with HttpMethod.releaseConnection() and EntityUtils.consume(entity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640811/problems-with-httpmethod-releaseconnection-and-entityutils-consumeentity)

Where one of the answer said that android comes with prepackages of httpclient libs. So just to check I removed my external HTTPClient libraries and eclipse annoys again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows error because android doesn't support this method. The best way to know would be press `.` and `Ctrl+space` then it will show all the methods available from that you can see that `releaseConnection()` is missing. So these methods will give a compilation error.

Comment: So how am i supposed to release connection then?

Comment: @AshwinSurana: In the question you have tagged, there it is mentioned that you should use `HttpUrlConnection` refer the blog post.